# Wordpress: wp_update_attachment_metadata returns empty array

Tags: php, wordpress, image, woocommerce, product

I manually uploaded some images in uploads subfolder with products sku as filename and I am trying to create a function to assign these images to the products.

But while I can see the image in the media list if I open one there is no photo inside (although in the list I can see the thumbnail). After debuging I narrowed the problem down to the wp_update_attachment_metadata which returns an empty array. How I can solve this? What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code :

```
function assign_images(){
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');

    $args = array(
    'orderby'  => 'name',
    );
    $products = wc_get_products( $args );  

    //get the dir where the photos are
    $upload_dir   = wp_upload_dir();
    $udir = $upload_dir['basedir'].'/photos_manual/Users/dev/Dropbox/new product photos/';

    foreach( $products as $p ){
        $sku = $p->get_sku();
        if($p->get_id() == 2982){ //for testing reasons
            $filename = $sku.'.jpg';
            $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype( $udir.$filename, null );
        
            
            $attachment = array(
                'post_mime_type' => 'image/jpeg',
                'post_title' => sanitize_file_name( preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', $filename) ),
                'post_content' => '',
                'post_status' => 'inherit'
            );
            $file = $udir.$filename;
            $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file ); 
            $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file ); //$attach_data is empty array
            wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
            set_post_thumbnail($p->get_id(), $attach_id); //die();
            
        }
    }
    exit();
      
    wp_die(); // ajax call must die to avoid trailing 0 in your response
    
}
```

Comment: See if this helps, You may missing the GUID parameter https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/238294/programmatically-adding-images-to-the-media-library-with-wp-generate-attachment

Comment: Nope didnt work either

Comment: What is the $attachment_id and $attach_data you getting for one of the sample uploads?

Comment: $attach_id is the post id of the image and $attach_data is empty array

Comment: Can you try with a directory without any spaces in the path?

Comment: tried that too... same thing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229817/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-netdev).

Comment: That’s strange, [according to documentation `wp_update_attachment_metadata` is not supposed to return an array at all](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_attachment_metadata/).

Comment: your code works on my local development. After `wp_insert_attachment` try adding a check encase there are any errors throwing. `if ( $attach_id != 0 || !is_wp_error($attach_id) )`

Comment: What's the result of `wp_get_registered_image_subsizes()` function. Do other photos in library have their thumbnail images?

Answer (score 0):

In general, the return value of `wp_update_attachment_metadata()` function is `int|false` as you can see in the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_attachment_metadata/).
But if you really get an empty array value from the function, there might be 2 reasons.

- `add_post_metadata` filter is defined somewhere in your plugins or theme, and it returns an empty array. `wp_update_attachment_metadata()` function calls `apply_filters( "add_post_metadata", ... )` behind. This is the only reason for the issue on proper WordPress install.
- You edited one of the following 4 functions in WordPress core that can affect the return value. `wp_update_attachment_metadata()`, `update_post_meta()`, `update_metadata()`, `add_metadata()`. If you didn't edit the core files, this is not the case, but it's nice to double check the functions.